# Custom ConstraintValidator unit test using Quarkus

Tags: constraints, quarkus, inject

I need to make validations on my custom ConstraintValidator that uses an @Inject needed for some validations, it's like this example  from quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/validation

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, String> {

    @Inject
    MyService service;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return service.validate(value);
    }
}
```

When i run the application I see that is made the right validation, but i'm trying to make unit test using mockito i can't mock the object is always null on the default using the Default Bean validation.

On the example from quarkus is unit test only for integration.

this is my implementation

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, String> {

    @Inject
    BookService service;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "my.property")
    int myLimit;

    public MyConstraintValidator(BookService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        System.out.println("myLimit property: " + myLimit);

        int limit = Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (limit < myLimit) {
            return service.validate(value);
        } else {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(NAME_EMPTY).addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Unit test for testing the custom Validator

```java
    @Test
    void testAmountValidationWithContext() {

        BookRequest bookRequest = new BookRequest();
        bookRequest.setTitle("my title");
        bookRequest.setAuthor("my Author");
        bookRequest.setPages(2L);
        bookRequest.setAmount("11");

        //when:
        myConstraintValidator = new MyConstraintValidator(service);
        Mockito.when(service.validate(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        //then:
        Set<ConstraintViolation<BookRequest>> violations = validator.validate(bookRequest);

        // verify that the context is called with the correct argument
        Mockito.verify(context).buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(NAME_EMPTY);

    }
```

The unit test to test the default @NoBlank.

```java
    @Test
    void testBeanValidationWithInvalidAmount() {
        BookRequest bookRequest = new BookRequest();
        bookRequest.setTitle("my title");
        bookRequest.setAuthor("my Author");
        bookRequest.setPages(2L);
        bookRequest.setAmount("AA");

        //when:
        Set<ConstraintViolation<BookRequest>> violations = validator.validate(bookRequest);

        //then:
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
        assertEquals(NOT_EMPTY, violations.stream().findFirst().get().getMessage());
    }
```

The first unit test works weel, i can mock the object and test the result.

The problem is on my second test, when i try to test the other validations @NotNull, @Pattern. On this test the method **isValid()** is also invoked and here it's my problem because the **@ConfigProperty** and the **@Inject** are always null, and i can't mocked them.

I already saw several examples over internet but doesn't work and are almost for spring but i need to make the custom validation on quarkus.

How can i implement the custom ConstraintValidator unit test using quarkus?

Does any one have any example with this working?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code from [field injection](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#qualified-injected-fields) to constructor injection will make unit testing much easier.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, String> {


    private final MyService service;
    private final int myLimit;

    public MyConstraintValidator(MyService service, @ConfigProperty(name = "my.property") int myLimit) {
       this.service = service;
       this.myLimit = myLimit;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) 
    {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return service.validate(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello.
that is a possible solution but will break the guide code of the company.
We only use the @Inject. so if we in future use another anotations we will have pass the control to the quarkus.

beside that i already need to implmente the ConfigProperty.

Comment: This code does not need `@Inject` - although you are free to add it to the constructor but in Quarkus it's optional (if there is a single constructor).  The whole idea of the answer is to use constructor injection instead of field injection as it makes testing much simpler

Comment: I also updated the answer to include the config property

Comment: implementing the @ in the constructor it's a good ideia? if we have alot of them?

Comment: You skip `@Inject` in the constructor only if there is a single constructor - if you have multiple ones, you need to use it on the constructor that Quarkus will use in order to create the object.

Answer (score 0):

Updated description with my implementations.
but resuming the issue.
when i have the default annotations with my custom validator i can't mock the objects using the

`Set<ConstraintViolation<BookRequest>> violations = validator.validate(bookRequest);`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).